# select SUM of a column with fetching number of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table like

```
student_id  student_name    subject marks
1              A            a_sub   10
1              A            a_sub   10
2              A            b_sub   5
3              A            c_sub   20
4              B            b_sub   10
```

from where I want to fetch `SUM(marks)` with all other columns for ex, `SELECT student_name, subject, SUM(marks) AS marks FROM records ORDER BY student_id`.

Result should be like:

```
student_name    subject marks
A               a_sub   45
B               b_sub   10
```

I tried with `GROUP BY` but it will not work as a `student_name` has different `subject` value

Comment: As you correctly mentioned, student A has multiple subjects. What is the rule to display `a_sub` instead of e.g. `c_sub`?

Comment: the first occurence @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: @softech . . . And how do you choose which subject gets shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the "first" subject, you can use `min()` and group by the name.

```
SELECT student_name, min(subject) as subject, SUM(marks) AS marks 
FROM records 
GROUP BY student_name
ORDER BY student_name;
```

Comment: I  think this is better than @muhammad answer, because if `no. of columns` increase I need to do more `subquery` in @muhammad answer or need to add all in `Group by`  which will affect performance, any suggestions? I need to do in ms sql

Answer (score 1):

You can get your output using this query

```
select distinct b.student_name, b.marks, (select top 1 subject from [records] where b.student_name = student_name)
from [records] a
inner join (
        SELECT student_name, SUM(marks) AS marks 
        FROM [records] 
        GROUP BY student_name) b on a.student_name = b.student_name
ORDER BY b.student_name
```

I have also tried on my end its working fine

Comment: This will be inconsistent bcz you want to show 45 infront of `a_sub` but 45 is total of `a_sub and b_sub and c_sub`

Comment: On what basis will you decide which subject to show with student name you are agregrating marks of single student and multiple subjects

Comment: I have updated my post and now you can get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function:

```
select distinct r.student_name, 
       first_value(r.subject) over (partition by r.student_name order by r.student_id) as subject,
       sum(r.marks) oever (partition by r.student_name) as marks
from records r;
```

Simple aggregation would also work :

```
select student_name, min(subject) as subject, sum(marks) as marks 
from records r 
group by student_name;
```